# Is there a way to use precomputed distances in Seaborn with the colour bar/bar code representation?

Tags: python, types, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm trying to use Seaborn to plot my dendrogram because its graphics are much better than the dendrograms I produced so far, but I need my graphs to show specific information and I'm having trouble getting Seaborn to do everything. I'm using a precomputed distance matrix because I'm using a novel distance measure this is making things more difficult. I have so far:

```
Data = read in the data, a dict of pairwise distance measures: {(User1, User2) : 0.0001445, (User1, User3): 0.593983, etc.......}
keys = [sorted(k) for k in Data.keys()]
values = Data.values()
sorted_keys, distances = zip(*sorted(zip(keys, values)))
Links = sch.linkage(distances, 'ward')
labels = sorted(set([key[0] for key in sorted_keys] + [sorted_keys[-1][-1]]))
Labels = pd.Series(labels)
lut = dict(zip(Labels.unique(), "rbgycm"))
row_colours = Labels.map(lut)

g = sns.clustermap(distances) #gives me a dendrogram and heatmap successfully. 
g = sns.clustermap(distances, row_color=row_colours) #gives me and error message
```

I want to use the second command to include the barcode style representation of each 'user' that a cluster, as in the [3rd example on Seaborn's clustermap docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html), but I get the error

```
 g = sns.clustermap(Links, row_colors=row_colours)
  File "/Users/.../seaborn/_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/.../seaborn/matrix.py", line 1400, in clustermap
    colors_ratio=colors_ratio, cbar_pos=cbar_pos)
  File "/Users/.../seaborn/matrix.py", line 813, in __init__
    self._preprocess_colors(data, row_colors, axis=0)
  File "/Users/.../seaborn/matrix.py", line 877, in _preprocess_colors
    colors = colors.reindex(data.index)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

In addition, Seaborn gives me the truncated dendrogram and then a heatmap of the 4 main clusters. I can only assume this is something generic, or it chose where to optimally cut the dendrogram. I hope to be able to specify the number of clusters, as I need 6. Is this possible?

This is what I have so far:

[image: plain dendrogram]

But I want to add this colour bar:

[image: dendrogram with colour bar]

Everything I've found on Seaborn includes a preloaded dataset and classic distance measure, and I'm new to using libraries and packages so I don't really know what it needs for this to work. I've tried using some wrappers to change the types but haven't got anything to work. I don't understand what difference the colourbar makes, why this brings a requirement for a new type despite the colour deciding command resulting in the same types and entries at the Iris example on the Seaborn site. It can manage the dendrogram from my `Links` variable. The colours are just labels and corresponding colours with indexes. I don't know what I'm missing to make it run.

Comment: Did you try ` g = sns.clustermap(Links, row_colors=row_colours.to_numpy())`? Did you upgrade to the latest seaborn version (0.11.1)?  Note that `lut = dict(zip(Labels.unique(), "rbgycm"))` only allows for 6 different users.  Are you trying to give each user a different color? Or what is the criterion for coloring? (The iris example colors each of the individual flowers via its species)

Comment: Thankyou! Upgrading from 0.11.0 to 0.11.1 and/or using .to_numpy() has worked! thankyou so much.

Comment: Yes I know the original groups that each instance belonged to so i know that there are 6. I  have another function to reduce them down to 6 labels but it wasn't important for this problem.